# combo box and its value through entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I want to show a value in Combo box from the data base through entity frame work but combo box is not showing the value.cmbCategory is the combobox

```
var cat = db.ItemSetups.Find(txtItemID.Text);
txtItemName.Text = cat.ItemName;
txtPrice.Text = cat.Price.ToString();
txtQuantity.Text = cat.Quantity.ToString();
cmbCategory.SelectedValue = cat.ItemCategory;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccnpQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the datasource for the combobox to know what items to display:

```
var categories = db.ItemCategory.ToList();//filter this as required
cmbCategory.DataSource = categories;
cmdCategory.DisplayItem = "CategoryName"; //or any display column you have
cmdCategory.ValueItem = "Id";
cmdCategory.SelectedItem = cat.ItemCategory;
```

This is how I would have done it.